# Vertically align and match angle of a shape to a line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, alignment, rotate

I'm trying to add a grouped pair of rectangles to many different radially ordered lines. Each line has a slightly different angle. I'm trying to have the center of the gray rectangle vertically aligned and matching the angle of the line. Is there a way to do this without painstakingly trying to match the black line's angle with the grouped rectangles by eye? I'm doing this for 728 lines arranged in a circle for a scientific figure.

[image: The gray rectangles need to be aligned vertically with its corresponding black line and it also needs to match the angle of the line]

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a circle that is in the middle of your chart
2. Make sure 1 set of the 2 rectangles is on the X axis
3. Press "R" to select the Rotate Tool, with both the 2 rectangles and the rotate tool selected, hold the "Alt" key and left click the center of the circle you created. You will rotate around that pivot point.
4. A popup will open, put 360/728 in the angle box.
5. Click on the "Copy" button, press CTRL (Windows) / CMD (Mac) + D to repeat the last transform action.

[image: Example Gif]

Comment: I have a Mac, does the alt key change? Is it option?

Comment: @JennaM Use the "Command" (CMD) key + D to repeat the rotate transform.

Comment: Well I was referring to the "alt" key when using the rotate tool, which seemed to work if I selected "option" instead. This worked! Thank you SO MUCH! Literally hours of work done in seconds--mind blown!